# Quartz.Net - Common Logging with log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, quartz.net-2.0, common.logging, log4net-configuration

I'm trying to implement Quartz.Net. As long as there is no logging configured everything works (the debug output shows *"no configuration section  found - suppressing logging output"*).

When logging is enabled I'll get the following error: **Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging'**.

Inner exeption: **An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for common/logging: Unable to create type 'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net'**

I used several resources as [this one](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/logging.html#logging-adapters-log4net) to varify my configuration, but as far as I see it should be correct.

My app.config:

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>  
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-6p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="Driver.Service.Scheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
  </quartz>
```

I referenced the following assemblies:
quartz.dll, version 2.01.100
common.logging.dll, version 2.0.0.0
common.logging.log4net.dll, version 2.0.0.0
log4net.dll, version 1.2.10.0

I cannot find a reason for the error given. All help is welcome, apparently I forget something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you check that Common.Logging.Log4net.dll is being copied to your bin output folder.

Also are you sure you don't have a inner exception on your inner exception (or maybe several levels of inner exceptions) ?

Comment: I already checked if the required dll's were copied to the bin folder of the library I'm building. What I did not check was the bin folder of the test console app, and that's where they were missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

We had similar situation when we upgraded to the new version of Common.Logging.Log4Net where the DLL name to changed to *Common.Logging.Log4Net1211* from *Common.Logging.Log4Net*.

So, we modified the configuration file to change DLL name:

```
<factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1211">
```

Anyway, the error definitely indicates missing DLL.

Comment: More information about this can be found at: https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/wiki/Common.Logging-Packaging-and-Versions

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but in your common/logging config section, one time its written log4net and one time its log4Net (capital letter):

```
  <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I compared it with a working Quartz example I downloaded and modified it. However, without result.